# Laravel Forge - Upgrading project to Laravel 8 needs PHP 7.4

Tags: php, laravel-forge

I recently migrated a Forge-hosted project to Laravel 8.x.  The deployment script fails when running `composer install`, all of the messages related to having the wrong PHP version:

```
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.4 but your PHP version (7.3.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for lcobucci/clock 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/clock[2.0.0].
    - lcobucci/clock 2.0.0 requires php ^7.4 || ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
...
```

### I did this though.

At least according to the [documentation](https://forge.laravel.com/docs/1.0/servers/php.html).  PHP 7.4 is selected in Meta > PHP Version for this site.  In PHP Management, 7.4 is default and is updated to latest patch.
[image]

I restarted PHP, then Nginx, then the entire server, none of it worked.

Via SSH it is using 7.3.26:

```
forge@mistaken-identity:~$ php -v
PHP 7.3.26-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2021 08:00:44) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.26, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.26-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Is Forge's PHP management API broken, or just on my server?   I would like to be able to set PHP version on a per-site basis.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10):

Found it.

Forge has a "Use on CLI" button on the PHP version management dashboard which is apparently what Composer looks at when deciding whether to install/upgrade dependencies.  Mine was still set to the 7.3 binary.

[image]

This is also briefly mentioned in the [blog post](https://blog.laravel.com/forge-multiple-php-installations) announcing the feature:

> In addition, you may determine which PHP version is the "default" version on the CLI. The default CLI PHP version is the version of PHP that will be executed when running the "php" command on the command line.